# Why ExtJS 'items' property behaves like static?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Each time when I call `Ext.create()`, new button pushes to the form. But `counter` still leave `== 1`

If I remove `items: []` and uncomment `Ext.apply(/*...*/)` all works correctly.

Why does the `items` property behaves like static?

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('TestForm', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
            title: 'TestForm',
            margin: 40,
            items: [], // remove it
            counter: 100,
            initComponent: function() {
                this.counter++;
                /*Ext.applyIf(this, {
                    items: []
                });*/
                this.items.push({ xtype: 'button', text: 'test'+this.counter})
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })

        Ext.create('TestForm');
        Ext.create('TestForm');
        Ext.create('TestForm');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a component is derived from the prototype, all members are passed - some by reference, some by value, depending on the type.

- The counter is an int, which is passed by value.
- Items is an array, which is passed by reference.

So if you define `items` array on the prototype, all instances point to the same `items` array.

Since you add the button config to that array (on which there are two references, one from the prototype and one from the instance), every time you create a new instance, a new button is added to that array, keeping the old ones.

Afterwards, in `callParent`, ExtJS iterates over the items property (then an array) and creates a MixedCollection of components from the array contents. The mixedCollection is then stored in the items property. During this, the reference breaks - this is why the first instance does not get the second button into its items.

To make sure that you don't run into these issues, there is one possibility:
**Never define pass-by-reference types as members of the prototype.**

What I would do:

```
    Ext.define('TestForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        title: 'TestForm',
        margin: 40,
        counter: 100,
        initComponent: function() {
            this.counter++;
            Ext.apply(this, {
                items: [{ xtype: 'button', text: 'test'+this.counter}]
            });
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    })
```

or

```
    Ext.define('TestForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        title: 'TestForm',
        margin: 40,
        counter: 100,
        initComponent: function() {
            this.counter++;
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.add({xtype: 'button', text: 'test'+this.counter});
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    })
```

The first one adds the items definition to every instance before it instantiates the component, the other one adds the button to the layout after the component has already been instantiated.